# Service Fabric Stateless api certification based authentication

Tags: azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi

I was asked to secure my stateless api endpoint using cert based authentication. I read about the subject, and realized I needed to create a middleware to inspect the request, and then check for the x-ARR-ClientCert header, to check whether the certificate is valid or not, based on some thumbprint. So far, so good.

The problem is that I can't test the middleware, because I don't have idea on how to send such a header. I already have a self signed certificate(.crt) and a key(.key). I tried with postman, but I can't see the x-ARR-ClientCert being sent while debugging on VS2017.

Any Help?

**Edit 1**

I'm following this tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2016/04/13/azure-web-app-client-certificate-authentication-with-asp-net-core-2/

I know it's a bit old, but at the end the writer shows the browser asking for a certificate, but I just can't manage for the browser to ask for the certificate.

One thing I forgot to mention here, is that my API is on a local Service Fabric Cluster, so that might be the problem

**Edit 2**

For Postman, I've followed this tutorial: [Postman Tutorial](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates/), but had no luck: first I had to turn off ssl check, and then when added the certificate to Postman, the x-ARR-ClientCert header wasn't being sent.

I've also tried curl: `> curl --cert cert.crt --key client.key https://localhost/api/values --insecure` but still the x-ARR-ClientCert isn't being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish...

In a mutual certificate authentication, the browser handles the authentication\certificate exchange, and when the user tries to access an endpoint secured by client certificate, the server tells the client(browser) that it requires a certificate to accept the connection and the browser popup a message to the user asking for a certificate to be used, there is a nice write about it [here](https://www.nevatech.com/blog/post/What-you-need-to-know-about-securing-APIs-with-mutual-certificates).

If the plan is to do it for automation, the postman blog has an [article](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/05/set-and-view-ssl-certificates-with-postman/) on how you setup client certificates for this scenario. The other option is trying to send the certificate using CURL as described [here](https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326).

Secondly, you are reinventing the wheel, there are already some ready to use implementations in kestrel using [`HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions.ClientCertificateMode = RequireCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.https.clientcertificatemode?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and some authorization middlewares [here](https://github.com/xavierjohn/ClientCertificateMiddleware) and [here](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication/tree/master/src/idunno.Authentication.Certificate).

And finally, make sure that there is no proxy in the middle or that the proxy or gateway is not removing the certificate from the client connection.